# SSActiveToolBars Infragistics control freeze on vb6 citrix environment

Tags: vb6, infragistics, citrix

I have an old software that written in VB6 with infragistics SSActiveToolBars control (ActiveThreedPlus). this software is running on a Citrix environment,
The problem is that after being idle for about 10 minutes SSActiveToolBars unresponsive while all other keyboard shortcuts are working and I have also timer label that continue to progress.

infragistics control who get stuck is SSActiveToolBars.

Apparently, we do use "seamless mode". However, it is only relevant for a very small percentage of our users, (the PC users), while more than 90% of our users use Terminals, and work on a Full Desktop, (and their application get stuck as well). Therefore as I understand there is no relevance in their case, to the "seamless mode" definition, I assume that this is not the solution to our problem.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but this controls (the famous Sheridan Controls) have no more support from Infragistics as you can see from [this document](http://download.infragistics.com/download/pubs/ProductLifeCycle.pdf) starting by Mar-2003. If you have the source I will try to change the controls to ActiveThreedPlus (also retired). Just to see if your problem was resolved.

Comment: @Steve Sorry we are using ActiveThreedPlus, I updated the question

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this outside of Citrix? For example, it could be related to the screen resolution, or something else that is different in the Citrix environment (i.e. if Citrix uses a 640x480 resolution, maybe it is really a bug at that resolution, and not something Citrix-specific). Just a guess.

Comment: @MikeSpross thanks, I already tried to change the resoultion but still no response. the stuck happens sometimes without repeting scenario

Comment: If you are using seamless mode, does turning off seamless mode correct the issue? http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/ica-settings/ica-settings-twimode.html

Comment: @DorCohen Seamless mode can affect how windows are recognized.  Depending on the implementation of the controls changing the setting may have an impact so I was suggesting that you test with seamless mode disabled to see if it affects the behavior.  For more details on seamless mode, the following topic may help: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/general/seamless-application-explained.html

Comment: Following the hint from @alhalama I have searched on Citrix if there is some known problems with VB6 applications and found this [article](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX109651). Don't know if it is applicable, but...

Comment: @alhalama Apparently, we do use "seamless mode".
However, it is only relevant for a very small percentage of our users, (the PC users),
while more than 90% of our users use Terminals, and work on a Full Desktop, (and their application get stuck as well).
Therefore as I understand there is no relevance in their case, to the "seamless mode" definition, 
I assume that this is not the solution to our problem.

Comment: @Steve I am not sure what else could affect the behavior without having an environment to test in which I don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with turning off DEP (Data Execution Prevention) for my software:

http://geekswithblogs.net/PsudoKnowledgeBase/archive/2009/06/03/turning-off-data-execution-prevention-dep.aspx

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/120778-dep-enable-disable.html

[image: turning off DEP]